# Angular2 Metadata version mismatch for module for boostrap

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-template, bootstrap-grid

how resolve this error :

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module C:/xampp/htdocs/organic-shop/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/organic-shop/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/organic-shop/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/organic-shop/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a mismatch between the version numbers of `Angular`/`ng-bootstrap`/`bootstrap` according to [this issue in ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2039).

What version of each one of them are you using?

To play safe check the dependencies section of [ng-bootstrap's README](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap). If you are using the latest `ng-bootstrap` (`1.0.0-beta.9`) then the required versions are:

- Angular (tested with 5.0.2)
- Bootstrap 4 (tested with 4.0.0-beta.3)

Comment: I too have the same issue. There is a mismatch between bootstrap version. It says found version 4, expected 3. My node version is 9.5.0. NPM version is 5.6.0